# S3 to Redshift: "Unknown boolean format"

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

[image: error]

I am trying to load data from a csv file from S3 to Redshift... and it contains data as 1.0 and 0.0 . how can i process this successfully. thanks

Comment: I have added an attachment image as 'error'. please check that if you have any questions.

Comment: Redshift accepts `1` and `0` as boolean values, but it appears that it doesn't accept `1.0` and `0.0`. You should either pre-process the file, or load the data as a `float` and then convert it via SQL queries later.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Redshift Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html), these are the valid literals accepted as BOOLEAN values

[image]

So to be able to upload your csv to Redshift with this specific column as BOOL you will have to process the data beforehand.

If you are using python (as your question tags suggests) you can easily do so with the pandas package or other that you have familiarity. But if it's a one time job and you don't bother doing it manually you can just change the column data type on your spreadsheet program (excel, googlesheets whatever) to remove the floating point or even replace values accordingly with any accepted literal strings.

Now, is your column really a boolean one ? "raw_field_value" doesn't look much as a flag column to me. If you have values that differs from 0, 1 or NULL than you should change your column type in Redshift to an appropriate one.

If in the end your column is really a bool value and you want to process your data using pandas here is a code snippet to help you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

df['raw_field_value'] = df['raw_field_value'].astype(int)

df = pd.to_csv('path/to/file.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

If you have trouble loading the csv data try changing the "sep" (separator) and "encoding" parameters.